# where clause in presto cutom connector

Tags: presto

I have written a custom connector for presto for which I now need to provide the support for "where" clause so that I can pass that information further to the REST Endpoint(Data Source) so that I get filtered results only.

Let me know if anyone knows how to access this information(from which object) so I can fulfill the above use case.

Any help/hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dheeraj

Comment: Were you able to do it? I am also interested in handling the WHERE and LIMIT statements.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the where clause, you need to provide the implementation for `getSplits` method of `ConnectorSplitManager`. You can get the constraints from `ConnectorTableLayoutHandle` object and fetch the corresponding splits.